# Persistent Data for Textarea with Coldfusion Variables?

Tags: html, forms, jquery-mobile, coldfusion

I'm working with forms to get better at doing them, since I think it's a good skill to have. I have a basic form with a few text inputs, radio buttons, and checkboxes, and I'm working with server side validation using coldfusion. One issue I've run into is involving persistent data. I can get persistence with every field except the last five. My textareas. Not sure if this is based in how they work, or how they differ from the other inputs, but I cant get them to do what I want. Just to clarify, in case there's any confusion, by being "persistent", I want the data to still be in the fields after hitting the "submit" button in case the validation fails.

Here is the code I have so far (I haven't implemented any server side validation yet, just client side, which is all commented out.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Survey Time!</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Theme/themes/cssTheme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Theme/themes/MonsterHunt.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["survey"]["code"].value;
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] < '0' || x[i] > '9')
        {
            alert("You cannot put any letters in a zip code.");
            return false;
        }
    }
if (x.length!=5) 
  {
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] < '0' || x[i] > '9')
            {
                alert("You cannot put any letters in a zip code.");
                return false;
            }
        }
      alert("You have entered an invalid zip code.");
      return false;
  }
var x=document.forms["survey"]["number"].value;
var patt=new RegExp("^1?\\W?\\s?\\W?\\d{3}\\W?\\W?\\d{3}\\W?\\d{4}$");
if(!patt.test(x))
{
    alert("You are a tool");
    return false;
}

var x=document.forms["survey"]["state"].value;
if (x.toUpperCase()!="AL" && x.toUpperCase()!="AK" && x.toUpperCase()!= "AZ" && x.toUpperCase()!= "AR" && x.toUpperCase()!= "CA" && x.toUpperCase()!= "CO" && x.toUpperCase()!= "CT" && x.toUpperCase()!= "DC" && x.toUpperCase()!= "DE" && x.toUpperCase()!= "FL" && x.toUpperCase()!= "GA" && x.toUpperCase()!= 
          "HI" && x.toUpperCase()!= "ID" && x.toUpperCase()!= "IL" && x.toUpperCase()!= "IN" && x.toUpperCase()!= "IA" && x.toUpperCase()!= "KS" && x.toUpperCase()!= "KY" && x.toUpperCase()!= "LA" && x.toUpperCase()!= "ME" && x.toUpperCase()!= "MD" && x.toUpperCase()!= 
          "MA" && x.toUpperCase()!= "MI" && x.toUpperCase()!= "MN" && x.toUpperCase()!= "MS" && x.toUpperCase()!= "MO" && x.toUpperCase()!= "MT" && x.toUpperCase()!= "NE" && x.toUpperCase()!= "NV" && x.toUpperCase()!= "NH" && x.toUpperCase()!= "NJ" && x.toUpperCase()!= 
          "NM" && x.toUpperCase()!= "NY" && x.toUpperCase()!= "NC" && x.toUpperCase()!= "ND" && x.toUpperCase()!= "OH" && x.toUpperCase()!= "OK" && x.toUpperCase()!= "OR" && x.toUpperCase()!= "PA" && x.toUpperCase()!= "RI" && x.toUpperCase()!= "SC" && x.toUpperCase()!= 
          "SD" && x.toUpperCase()!= "TN" && x.toUpperCase()!= "TX" && x.toUpperCase()!= "UT" && x.toUpperCase()!= "VT" && x.toUpperCase()!= "VA" && x.toUpperCase()!= "WA" && x.toUpperCase()!= "WV" && x.toUpperCase()!= "WI" && x.toUpperCase()!= "WY")
  {
      alert("You have entered an invalid State. Must use two letter abbreviations.");
      return false;
  }
  if(!validateRadio(document.forms["survey"]["checkbox1a"]))
  {
       alert("You have failed to check at least one box for every question.");
       return false;
  }
  if(!validateRadio(document.forms["survey"]["checkbox2a"]))
  {
       alert("You have failed to check at least one box for every question.");
       return false;
  }
  if(!validateRadio(document.forms["survey"]["checkbox3a"]))
  {
       alert("You have failed to check at least one box for every question.");
       return false;
  }
  if(!validateRadio(document.forms["survey"]["checkbox4a"]))
  {
       alert("You have failed to check at least one box for every question.");
       return false;
  }
  if(!validateRadio(document.forms["survey"]["checkbox5a"]))
  {
       alert("You have failed to check at least one box for every question.");
       return false;
  }
  alert("Thank you for submitting the form!");
  return true;
}
function validateRadio (radios)
{
   for (i = 0; i < radios.length; ++ i)
   {
       if (radios [i].checked) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<cfparam name="form.fname" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.lname" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.mname" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.address" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.email" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.number" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.city" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.state" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.code" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice1" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice2" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice3" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice4" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice5" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice6" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice7" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice8" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice9" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice10" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice11" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice12" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice13" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice14" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.radiochoice15" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.checkbox1a" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.checkbox2a" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.checkbox3a" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.checkbox4a" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.checkbox5a" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.textarea1" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.textarea2" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.textarea3" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.textarea4" default=""/>
<cfparam name="form.textarea5" default=""/>
<div data-role="page" id='first'>
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Have we got a form for you!</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
    <cfoutput>
        <form action="form.cfm" method="post" name="survey"> <!-- creating the form for inputting search data -->
                <input type="text" name="fname" required="required" value="#form.fname#" id="fname" placeholder="*First Name">
                <input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" name="mname" value="#form.mname#" id="mname" placeholder="Middle Initial">
                <input type="text" name="lname" required="required" id="lname" value="#form.lname#" placeholder="*Last Name">
                <input type="email" name="email" value="#form.email#" required="required" id="email" placeholder="*Email Address">
                <input type="text" name="address" value="#form.address#" required="required" id="address" placeholder="*Street Adress">
                <input type="tel" name="number" value="#form.number#" required="required" id="number" maxlength="14" placeholder="*Phone Number">
                <input type="text" name="city" value="#form.city#" required="required" id="city" placeholder="*City">
                <input type="text" maxlength="2" value="#form.state#" required="required" name="state" id="state" placeholder="*State">
                <input type="text" name="code" value="#form.code#" required="required" id="code" maxlength="5" placeholder="*Zip Code">
                                <cfif isDefined("form.submit")>
                    <cfif form.radiochoice1 EQ "" >
                        <text color="Red" align="center" class="error">*answer this question</text>
                    </cfif>
                </cfif>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Who would win in a fight?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice1" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice1 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Me</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice1" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice1 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">You</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice1" id="radiochoice3"  value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice1 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">Him</label>                        
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Which is better, cats or dogs?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice2" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice2 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Cats</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice2" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice2 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">Dogs</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice2" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice2 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">Neither. European Guinea Pigs</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Are you a jerk?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice3" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice3 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Yeah</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice3" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice3 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">Nope</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice3" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice3 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">WHO WANTS TO KNOW?</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Do you love me?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice4" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice4 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Yeah</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice4" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice4 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">Nope</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice4" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice4 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">My love for you is like a flock of lemons</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Do I scare you?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice5" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice5 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Yeah</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice5" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice5 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">Nope</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice5" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice5 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">GET AWAY FROM ME</label>
                </fieldset>
                 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Wanna go to Disney World?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice6" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice6 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Yay Disney!</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice6" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice6 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">No. I hate mice</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice6" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice6 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">AWMAIGAWD DISNEY</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice6" id="radiochoice4" value="d" <cfif form.radiochoice6 EQ "d">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice4">I want Disney LAND</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Is all fair in love and war?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice7" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice7 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Yeah</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice7" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice7 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">Nope</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice7" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice7 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">I dont love you or want to kill you, so I dont care</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Am I cool?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice8" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice8 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Yeah! You Rock!</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice8" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice8 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">No, you're lame.</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice8" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice8 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">What is "cool"?</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Do you like cake, pie, or brownies?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice9" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice9 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Cake</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice9" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice9 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">Pie</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice9" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice9 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">Brownies</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Do you like hamsters, mice, or gerbils?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice10" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice10 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Hamsters</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice10" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice10 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">Mice</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice10" id="radiochoice3"  value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice10 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">Gerbils</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Would you like fries with that?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice11" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice11 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Yes</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice11" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice11 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">No</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice11" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice11 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">I knew you'd be saying that one day</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*What School do you go to?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice12" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice12 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Carthage</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice12" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice12 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">Somewhere lamer than Carthage</label>
                    <input disabled = "disabled" type="radio" name="radiochoice12" id="radiochoice3" value="choice-3">
                    <label for="radiochoice3">Somewhere cooler than Carthage (This answer is invalid)</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*On a scale of 1-10, how awesome am I?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice13" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice13 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">10</label>
                    <input disabled = "disabled" type="radio" name="radiochoice13" id="radiochoice2" value="choice-2">
                    <label for="radiochoice2">7-9</label>
                    <input disabled = "disabled" type="radio" name="radiochoice13" id="radiochoice3" value="choice-3">
                    <label for="radiochoice3">4-6</label>
                    <input disabled = "disabled" type="radio" name="radiochoice13" id="radiochoice4" value="choice-4">
                    <label for="radiochoice4">1-3</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*What is a horse?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice14" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice14 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">Yes</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice14" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice14 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">No</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice14" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice14 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">A wee snaw</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*WEE SNAW</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice15" required="required" id="radiochoice1" value="a" <cfif form.radiochoice15 EQ "a">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice1">WEE</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice15" id="radiochoice2" value="b" <cfif form.radiochoice15 EQ "b">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice2">SNAW</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice15" id="radiochoice3" value="c" <cfif form.radiochoice15 EQ "c">checked="checked"</cfif>>
                    <label for="radiochoice3">SNAW WEE</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Pick some chips</legend>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1a" id="checkbox1a" value="a" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox1a,"a") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox1a">Cheetos</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1a" id="checkbox2a" value="b" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox1a,"b") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox2a">Doritos</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1a" id="checkbox3a" value="c" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox1a,"c") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox3a">Fritos</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1a" id="checkbox4a" value="d" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox1a,"d") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox4a">Sun Chips</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*What's your favorite kind of person?</legend>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2a" id="checkbox1a" value="a" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox2a,"a") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox1a">Nice</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2a" id="checkbox2a" value="b"  <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox2a,"b") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox2a">Mean</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2a" id="checkbox3a" value="c"  <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox2a,"c") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox3a">Funny</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2a" id="checkbox4a" value="d"  <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox2a,"d") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox4a">Stoic</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Pick your favorite letter:</legend>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3a" id="checkbox6" value="a" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox3a,"a") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox6">q</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3a" id="checkbox7" value="b" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox3a,"b") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox7">m</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3a" id="checkbox8" value="c" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox3a,"c") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox8">z</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*Check all the colors you're currently wearing:</legend>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4a" id="checkbox1a" value="a" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox4a,"a") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox1a">Blue</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4a" id="checkbox2a" value="b" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox4a,"b") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox2a">Green</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4a" id="checkbox3a" value="c" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox4a,"c") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox3a">Red</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4a" id="checkbox4a" value="d" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox4a,"d") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox4a">White</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>*What should all the single ladies do?</legend>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5a"id="checkbox1a" value="a" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox5a,"a") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox1a">Put a ring on it if they like it</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5a" id="checkbox2a" value="b" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox5a,"b") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox2a">Put their hands up</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5a" id="checkbox3a" value="c" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox5a,"c") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox3a">Buy a goat</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5a" id="checkbox4a" value="d" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox5a,"d") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
                    <label for="checkbox4a">Go bowling</label>
                </fieldset>                
                    <textarea placeholder="*Would you like to input some lovely text?" value="#form.textarea1#" required="required" cols="40" rows="5" name="textarea1" id="textarea1"></textarea>
                    <textarea placeholder="*How about some more?" required="required" value="#form.textarea2#"  cols="40" rows="5" name="textarea2" id="textarea2"></textarea>
                    <textarea placeholder="*But I bet you'd love to type more stuffs" value="#form.textarea3#" required="required"  cols="40" rows="5" name="textarea3" id="textarea3"></textarea>
                    <textarea placeholder="Tell me about your pet panda:" cols="40" value="#form.textarea4#" rows="5" name="textarea4" id="textarea4"></textarea>
                    <textarea placeholder="Why do you love the dance?" cols="40" value="#form.textarea5#" rows="5" name="textarea5" id="textarea5"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit" data-inline="true"/>
        </form>
        </cfoutput>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        /* $('#survey').submit(function () {
           $.mobile.changePage( "#ThankYou", {
                type: "post",
                data: $("form#submit").serialize()
            });
            return validateForm();

        });*/
        </script>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never worked with ColdFusion, but Textarea doesn't have a `value` attribute. You specify text in a textarea by using:

```
<textarea>blah blah ......</textarea>
```

So I think this:

```
<textarea placeholder="*Would you like to input some lovely text?" 
   required="required" 
   cols="40" 
   rows="5" 
   name="textarea1" 
   id="textarea1"
   value="#form.textarea1#">
</textarea>
```

should be:

```
<textarea placeholder="*How about some more?" 
    required="required" 
    cols="40" 
    rows="5" 
    name="textarea2" 
    id="textarea2">#form.textarea2#</textarea>
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. Thank you so much! I was wondering why I couldn't find the value tag in the documentation...